# Getting different position values using Analyzer API in ES 1.4 and ES 2.3

Tags: elasticsearch, search-engine, similarity

I am upgrading from ES 1.4 to ES 2.3 and while testing the scoring of the documents I noticed a difference between the outputs from the Explain API for the same query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "article_content": "news"
        }
    }
}
```

From ES 2.3.0 I get:

```
{
  "value": 0.9890914,
  "description": "fieldWeight in 3931, product of:",
  "details": [
    {
      "value": 5.8309517,
      "description": "tf(freq=34.0), with freq of:",
      "details": [
        {
          "value": 34,
          "description": "termFreq=34.0",
          "details": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 5.428089,
      "description": "idf(docFreq=117, maxDocs=9885)",
      "details": []
    },
    {
      "value": 0.03125,
      "description": "fieldNorm(doc=3931)",
      "details": []
    }
  ]
}
```

and from ES 1.4.2 I get:

```
{
  "value": 0.9319723,
  "description": "fieldWeight in 403, product of:",
  "details": [
    {
      "value": 5.8309517,
      "description": "tf(freq=34.0), with freq of:",
      "details": [
        {
          "value": 34,
          "description": "termFreq=34.0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 5.114622,
      "description": "idf(docFreq=226, maxDocs=13899)"
    },
    {
      "value": 0.03125,
      "description": "fieldNorm(doc=403)"
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought that there might be something wrong with my `custom_analyzer`, so checked even that using the Analyze API:

For ES 2.3 I used:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/new_index/_analyze' -d '{
  "analyzer" : "custom_text_analyzer",
  "text" : "...."
}'
```

and for ES 1.4.2 I used

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9210/new_index2/_analyze?analyzer=custom_text_analyzer' -d '...'
```

Both calls resulted in the same number of tokens, the only difference was values of `"position"`:

For ES 2.3.0

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "show",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }, ....
```

For ES 1.4.2

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "show",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }, ....
```

NOTE:

- Both the indices have same documents in count and content.
- The document that I tested had 289 tokens
- The custom analyzer is same for both indices. (I checked twice)

I just wanted some insight into what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in scoring is here:

**2.3.0**:

```
{
  "value": 5.428089,
  "description": "idf(docFreq=117, maxDocs=9885)",
  "details": []
}
```

**1.4.2**:

```
{
  "value": 5.114622,
  "description": "idf(docFreq=226, maxDocs=13899)"
}
```

So the [IDF](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html#idf) is different because you seem to have a different number of documents and different number of frequency of terms in those documents. You say you have equal number of documents, but [`maxDocs` takes into consideration **all** documents in a Lucene shard](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3578#issuecomment-23325899). **All** includes the marked-as-deleted documents.

My assumption is that your 1.4.x index also has some deleted documents in it (which weren't yet physically deleted from disk from merging segments) and these ones influence a bit the scoring calculations. You can check the deleted documents count with `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v"` and you can force a merge by using the [_optimize](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html#optimize-api) API (`curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_optimize?max_num_segments=1"`). Be careful, though, that the optimization does use a bit of resources so you'd want to do this when the cluster is not busy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that the es 2.3 as well as 1.4 had a lot of deleted documents so, to make them exactly the same, I optimized both of them. Since both have 300,000 docs, so it did not take a lot of time. But still for 2.3 I get `idf(docFreq=108, maxDocs=9543)` and for 1.4 I am getting `idf(docFreq=226, maxDocs=13899)`. Could there be something else?

Comment: So, right now you have 0 deleted documents on both indices, correct?

Comment: Yes, I can see that.

Comment: How are the indices structured (number of shards, number of replicas)?

Comment: I have a total of 24 shards and 1 replica!

Comment: I mean for `new_index` in 2.3.x and `new_index2` in 1.4.x.

Comment: It is the same for both. The number of shards and replicas and number of documents are the same

Comment: Then I'd say the numbers are different because the documents in a single shard are different. And the TF/IDF algorithms are computed per shard. What I would try next? Migrate the 1.4.x index to 2.3.x (meaning upgrade the 1.4.x cluster to 2.3.x). In this way the content of the shards will be the same and the scoring should be the same.

Comment: What do mean by migration? You mean I should initiatlise a new index and point it the data of 1.4 ?

Comment: No. Since you have two indices - one in 1.4 and one in 2.3 - I'm assuming you have two clusters. Upgrade the 1.4 one.

Comment: Okay, I get it. This way the documents will remain as it is on the disk and rest everything will be updated? So, this means I will have to point the data directory of the new indices to the previous data directory?

Comment: Yes, the documents will be exactly the same and their distribution in shards the same. If, after the upgrade, the computations are different I'd look for changes in the algorithms but I doubt the scoring will differ. Regarding pointing data dir to a new folder, I haven't tried this before. If the cluster name is the same in 1.4 and 2.3 cluster, I'd try this, but I'd be careful.

Comment: I am getting confused on one point. On my previous cluster, if I already have 1.4.2 running, how will I migrate? Do I need to like remove the previous ES installation and replace it with new one? Earlier I was jus reindexing the same data on different clusters

Comment: [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-upgrade.html) is the official set of instructions for upgrading to 2.x from 1.x. Install 2.3 in a separate folder and change the paths for `config` and `data` folders to point to the "old" folders. Before doing this, make sure to take a snapshot, in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Since we were just testing whether or not the scores are same for both versions. So, instead of doing an in-place migration we decided to index all 300,000 documents in a single shard and it gave same scores on both. So, it was mainly about the distribution of documents that was causing the discrepancy. Thanks for your help.